# How to isolate a linearly correlating subset from data?

Tags: correlation, linear, subset

I have a data set of a few thousand data points, and some of them show strong linear correlation. I would like to isolate these data points into their own subsets. What would be the best approach for this?

[image]

Comment: Providing the dataset would probably help a lot for a more precise answer. As for the group on the left you might be able to catch those with a cluster analysis (or linear discriminant analysis). As for the group on the right, I do not see how i would do that manually for $-4<x<3$ for $x>3.5$ maybe find intercept and slope of the line and find the points near that line??

Comment: Not a particularly statistical answer here, but it looks like these relationships are $f(x) = \pm x$. You could run a search for `y == x` with a small error tolerance and then a second for `y == -x` with a small error tolerance (have a play with different tolerances, see what works). You will probably get some false positives with this approach but it should help you extract most of the relevant data, and then you might be able to manually pick out the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the linear data points are indeed points where $f(x) = \pm x$, as suggested in the comments. Thus, the points are easy to pick out. In a case where the slope was not exactly $\pm 1$, some kind of accuracy limit and line fitting would probably be the best solution.